# Copy .txt file to postgres table

Tags: postgresql

My txt file is as follows:

```
DE  DEBR    40  0   4WD Offroader   0   0   20020123
DE  DEDE    10  0   PKW Personenwagen   0   0   20020123
DE  DEDE    20  0   GLW Gel‰ndewagen    0   0   20020123
CH  CHBR    60  0       Motorcycle  0   0   20020429
CH  CHDE    10  0   PKW Personenwagen   0   0   20020429
CH  CHDE    20  0   NFZ Leichte Nutzfahrzeuge   0   0   20020429
CH  CHDE    60  0   ZWR Motorr‰der  0   0   20020429
CH  CHFR    10  0   VP  Voiture particulier 0   0   20020429
CH  CHFR    20  0   VU  Voiture utilitaire  0   0   20020429
CH  CHFR    60  0       Motocyclette    0   0   20020429
CH  CHIT    10  0       Autovetture 0   0   20020429
CH  CHIT    20  0       Veicoli industriali 0   0   20020429
```

And I want to copy it to a postgres table using:

```
COPY consumer FROM 'path/to/file' DELIMITER E'\t';
```

But I'm getting an error

```
[2017-06-19 10:38:50] [22P04] ERROR: extra data after last expected column
[2017-06-19 10:38:50] Where: COPY consumer, line 1: "DE DEBR    40  0   4WD Offroader   0   0   20020123"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have some tabs at the end of you rows. Could you not add an additional column to your table to capture these then drop the column when you are done ? It would save having to manage the source csv file.